# Keras LSTM online learning

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a sequence that is very predictable. Below, you can see a slice of it:

```
deque([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4])
```

Basically, it's a varying but still predictable number of 4s, followed by an 8, and by 28 every three 8s.

I want to build a very simple LSTM model for online prediction: each time a new number arrives, it is appended on the right of the deque. Thus, the LSTM is trained on the old sequence comprised of *[0:seq_length]* elements of the deque, with the training target being the *[seq_length]* element. Then, the window shifts and prediction is performed on the [1:seq_length+1] elements. At the end, the leftmost element of the deque is discarded. My intuition tells me that this should make the network memorize the sequence.

However, my network has been answering only 4. After a (long) while, surprisingly, it starts answering only 8, missing almost all of the time. And then, a (long) while later, it goes back to answering only 4.

My model is structured as shown. Naturally, I've already experimented with different values for *seq_length* and *lstm_cells*, none of which gave me success. These were from the latest run:

```
seq_length = 64  #Length of the sequence to be inserted into the LSTM
vocab_size = 4  #Size of the final dense layer of the model
lstm_cells = 16  #Size of the LSTM layer

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_cells, input_shape=(seq_length, 1)))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

The following is how data is prepared, trained, and predicted on the model. The variable *sequence* is the deque shown at the start of this post. I maintain a list *vocab = [4,8,28]* that is built on execution time as new numbers are seen, so *vocab[i]* translates class *i* into its corresponding number of the sequence. I then create a dictionary *legend* to do the opposite. This is more or less the ongoing online loop:

```
while True:

    # Receives new number and puts it into the deque:
    sequence.append(generateNextNumber())

    # At this point, please note that the length of the deque is seq_length + 1.

    # Dictionary to convert numbers to classes:
    legend = dict([(v, k) for k, v in enumerate(vocab)])
    # Converts the deque into a list:
    seq_list = list(sequence)
    # Each iteration is comprised of 1 training and 1 prediction. These are the training sequence and target:
    train_seq = [ [legend[i]] for i in seq_list[:seq_length] ]
    train_target = legend[ seq_list[seq_length] ]
    # And the prediction sequence just shifts the window by 1:
    pred_seq = [ [legend[i]] for i in seq_list[1:] ]

    # Batches data into a batch of size 1:
    x = np.zeros((1, seq_length, 1))
    y = np.zeros((1, vocab_size))
    x[0,:] = train_seq
    y[0,:] = to_categorical( train_target, num_classes=vocab_size )
    # Online training:
    model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=0)

    # Now that one training step is done, make a prediction:
    x_pred = np.zeros((1, seq_length, 1))
    x[0,:] = pred_seq
    predicted_onehot = model.predict(x_pred)
    # Avoids "index out of range" erros when the LSTM vocab is still being built:
    predicted_index = min(np.argmax(predicted_onehot), len(vocab)-1)
    predicted_number = vocab[ predicted_index ]
    # Reverts deque length to seq_length:
    sequence.popleft()
```

And, finally, this is an example output:

```
HIT! Current hit rate: 34.753665869071725 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]))

HIT! Current hit rate: 34.75566735175926 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]))

Predicted 4 but it was 8

HIT! Current hit rate: 34.75660255820374 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4]))

HIT! Current hit rate: 34.758603766640086 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4]))

HIT! Current hit rate: 34.7606048523142 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4]))

HIT! Current hit rate: 34.76260581523739 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4]))

HIT! Current hit rate: 34.76460665542095 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]))

HIT! Current hit rate: 34.76660737287616 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]))

Predicted 4 but it was 28

HIT! Current hit rate: 34.767541707556425 (predicted: 4, sequence was: deque([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 4]))
```

What is going so wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: my guess is that the most efficient behavior for the LSTM is to always predict 4s, as some 90% of the digit are the same. Try to make it predict a sinusoidal wave or something similar and you should see it learning it very quickly without changing architecture

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I've just tried the recurring sequence 4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 28. At the start, the LSTM is somewhat split between predicting 4 and 8, but after a while it just starts predicting 4 all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue in line:

```
x[0,:] = pred_seq
```

which was supposed to be:

```
x_pred[0,:] = pred_seq
```

Now everything is working more or less correctly. I'll still leave this question here since it offers some nice insights into LSTM online learning.